# foreach loop looping once for given array

Tags: php, json, laravel

My array

```
{"_token":"NeTBqkwEBqSD9AiXQ3lrIbGyos0sHKD5FEhJRdsW","questionnaires_id":null,"Int1":"2345","type":"1","asdf":"1","eq":"2018-08-02","radio_btn":"0","checkbox":"1"}
```

My code

```
$datas = $request->all();

foreach ($datas as $key => $data)
{
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: `return` will exit out of the loop/function, why do you think you need it here?

Comment: i got it, just want to see all the data from my array

Comment: If this is just for debugging purposes, use something like `print_r($datas);` as it will show the full structure of the data.

Comment: You need some sort of view to "see" the data.

Comment: yes, it is just debugging purposes

Comment: In laravel you can use `dd` helper function, that dumps the data in a nice readable way, e.g. `dd($data)`. Just put it somewhere in your code, `dd` also stops further execution.

Answer (score 0):

This `{"_token":"NeTBqkwEBqSD9AiXQ3lrIbGyos0sHKD5FEhJRdsW","questionnaires_id":null,"Int1":"2345","type":"1","asdf":"1","eq":"2018-08-02","radio_btn":"0","checkbox":"1"}`
is not an array.
This is [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

So:

1) convert JSON to array

```
$json = '{"_token":"NeTBqkwEBqSD9AiXQ3lrIbGyos0sHKD5FEhJRdsW","questionnaires_id":null,"Int1":"2345","type":"1","asdf":"1","eq":"2018-08-02","radio_btn":"0","checkbox":"1"}';

$array = json_decode($json, true); //true for associative array representation

print_r($array);

//result:
Array
(
    [_token] => NeTBqkwEBqSD9AiXQ3lrIbGyos0sHKD5FEhJRdsW
    [questionnaires_id] => 
    [Int1] => 2345
    [type] => 1
    [asdf] => 1
    [eq] => 2018-08-02
    [radio_btn] => 0
    [checkbox] => 1
)
```

2) then loop the array

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    //do something with $key or $value
}
```